# Probability problem with urns with multiple draws without replacement.

Tags: probability

> Consider two urns with the following composition: Urn $1$ contains $7$ red
> and $3$ black balls, Urn $2$ contains $4$ red and $6$ black balls. Our random
> experiment consists of choosing one of the two urns with equal
> probability and then drawing a sample (without replacement) of $3$
> balls. If $3$ red balls are drawn, what is the probability they came
> from Urn $1$?

Let $R$ be the event that three red balls are drawn without replacement. Let $U1$ be the event that Urn $1$ is chosen. Then by Bayes theorem, $$P(U1|R) = \frac{P(R|U1)P(U1)}{P(R)}$$ where

$$P(R|U1) = (7/10)(6/9)(5/8)$$ and
$$P(U1) = 0.5$$

Edit: I badly misread the question, the sample is three at a time.

Comment: $P(R\mid U1) = (7/10)\times (6/9)\times (5/8)$ which is not quite what you have; $P(U1)=\frac12$. Meanwhile $P(R)= P(R\mid U1)P(U1)+P(R\mid U2)P(U2)$

Comment: @Henry please see the comment that I left following my answer.  This was in response to the OP's comment, that he then deleted.  In your opinion, have I misinterpreted the problem?

Comment: Actually, it is unclear whether you misread the question.  The phrase "...choosing one of the two urns with equal probability" could intend that an urn is selected at random, for each of the $3$ ball selections.  Although this is not how I interpreted the problem, the ambiguous nature of the wording still leaves this interpretation as feasible.  See also, the comment that I left following my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 I read the question as "choosing one of the two urns with equal probability" and then "drawing a sample (without replacement) of 3 balls" from that urn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $~\displaystyle p_1 ~\text{denote} ~\frac{\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}.$

Let $~\displaystyle p_2 ~\text{denote} ~ \frac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}.$

Then, in accordance with [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem), the probability that the balls came from Urn 1 is

$$\frac{p_1}{p_1 + p_2} = \frac{\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{7}{3} + \binom{4}{3}}.$$

Comment: @IntegrateThis Not possible, according to how I (**subjectively**) interpret the problem's wording: "Our random experiment consists of choosing one of the two urns with equal probability and then drawing a sample (without replacement) of 3 balls. "  I am assuming that after the urn is chosen, all $3$ of the balls are taken from that Urn.  If this is an incorrect interpretation of the problem composer's intent, please edit your question to clarify this point, and I will then edit my answer.